# I'm getting error No JSON object could be decoded but with a valid JSON file

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django-Smuggler to upload JSON data to my database.

When I load a JSON file I'm getting the error: `No JSON object could be decoded`

I used online JSON validators to make sure the data is valid and it is. I got that data by doing a data dump.

Anyone know why this is happening?

This is where the exception is being raised (starred):

```
try:
    for format, stream in data:
        objects = serializers.deserialize(format, stream)
        for obj in objects:
            model = obj.object.__class__
            if router.allow_syncdb(using, model):
                models.add(model)
                counter += 1
                obj.save(using=using)
    if counter > 0:
        sequence_sql = connection.ops.sequence_reset_sql(style, models)
        if sequence_sql:
            for line in sequence_sql:
                cursor.execute(line)
**except Exception, e:**
    transaction.rollback(using=using)
    transaction.leave_transaction_management(using=using)
    raise e
```

Also here is my general format of JSON file:

```
[
  {
"pk": 1, 
"model": "auth.message", 
"fields": {
  "message": "Successfully uploaded a new avatar.", 
  "user": 1
}
      }, 
  {
"pk": 2, 
"model": "auth.message", 
"fields": {
  "message": "You have saved model 'mymodel'", 
  "user": 1
}
  }, 
      {
"pk": 3, 
"model": "auth.message", 
"fields": {
  "message": "You have saved model 'sdfsd'", 
  "user": 1
}
  }, 
  {
"pk": 4, 
"model": "auth.message", 
"fields": {
  "message": "Successfully uploaded a new avatar.", 
  "user": 1
}
  }, 
  {
"pk": 5, 
"model": "auth.message", 
"fields": {
  "message": "Successfully updated your avatar.", 
  "user": 1
}
  }
]
```

Comment: Show us some code to see what happens

Comment: Without at least the input and output you are using, we can't tell you much.  Plus, you are really asking a question about using a GUI tool for JSON parsing and DB updates, which isn't exactly what StackExchange is about, I think.  Maybe SuperUser or something?

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything new, really.  Clearly, the JSON parser in Python thinks something is wrong with your JSON string.  Without being able to see the JSON, it's pretty impossible to tell what.

Comment: Thanks I also added the JSON. It's a ridiculously long file so I just posted a snippet. There are some escaped unicode characters. Could encoding or unsupported characters cause this problem?

Comment: Possible, though unlikely, I think.  What happens if you throw the JSON snippet you posted here at the tool?

Comment: Good idea. That worked. Let me try to keep iteratively add portions and try to hone down on the area causing the problem. Thanks for the idea! :-)

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove the very last ',' character in the JSON string.

Comment: Do you mean the very last one because it's the last element? If yes, that might not be the problem because I was just posting a snippet and in fact the last element in my file doesn't have a comma.

Comment: Thanks German, I did use that site before posting here and all was fine.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to this but your JSON file might not be so valid even though it passed jsonlint. Check if it uses UTF-8 **without BOM** encoding.